# Directional collision detection between two rectangles

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, collision

So I need some help with my C# XNA top-down 2D "wave spawn" game. Basically, I have a player that has the functionality of shooting a laser at enemies that spawn in waves. The problem that I'm looking at fixing right now is my **enemy** collision code with a **stationary non-rotated wall (rectangle)**

I need to detect which side the enemy hits the rectangle on so he can properly get around the rectangle and to the player. (Example: if the enemy is blocked from the right side of the wall, move up the wall until he can get around the wall)

Here is the code I have to detect the angle between the enemy and the stationary wall when collided:

```
// I am blocked, find angle to find which side I'm blocked from
centerOfWall = wall.CenterOfWall;
Vector2 difference = centerOfWall - centerOfEnemy;
// Getting the angle of intersection between the two rectangles!
angle = Math.Atan2(difference.X, difference.Y);
// Converting angle to degrees!
degrees = angle * (180 / MathHelper.Pi);
```

I guess what I'm asking is, with this angle, can I find the side at which the enemy hits the wall? Like if the angle is less than 90 degrees but greater than 0 degrees I will be hitting from the Left or something like that.

If this doesn't work, can someone help me in finding another way that would work?

Thanks,

Johan

Comment: Here is one possible answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19202228/394923

Comment: Steve, thanks for pointing me to that answer, it worked out nicely!