# Draw a hypothetical line in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

So in my game a have this paddle and a ball, and i want to calculate which side of the paddle that the ball hits, i found this answer in C# which shows drawing two lines like this:

[image: Point of contact]

So what i want to do is draw two hypothetical lines(meaning invisible to the user) so i can calculate if the ball is greater then both the lines or if its in contact with one of the sides of the paddle.

How do i draw these lines in sprite kit and swift?

***UPDATE***

I found the original answer, its [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198359/how-to-determine-which-side-of-a-rectangle-collides-with-a-circle?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine which side of a rectangle collides with a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198359/how-to-determine-which-side-of-a-rectangle-collides-with-a-circle)

Comment: No thats a different language, not a duplicate

Comment: yup, you're correct. disregard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the position of the ball in relation to the paddle.

```
If(ballNode.position.x > paddleNode.position.x) {
    // ball is on the right of the paddle
} else {
    // ball is on the left of the paddle
}

If(ballNode.position.y > paddleNode.position.y) {
    // ball is above the paddle
} else {
    // ball is below the paddle
}
```